# CSS Additive Sizing

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with designing my own grid system. I decided to go with something that splits columns on percentage i.e. 10% 20% 30% etc. So I have Col-10 for a column that is 10%.

However, instead of doing a lot of coding, I want instead to use some sort of additive method. Think of it like money.

You have 100 note, a 50 note, a 20 note, a 10 note a 5 note and a bunch of small coins usually of the same denomination 100p coin, 50p coin, 20p coin, 10p coin, 5p coin and of course the all important 2p and 1p.

There is no 77 note. That would be made of 50, 20, and 5 notes, and 2 x 100p coins.

I want to do likewise with CSS. Instead of defining and using a specific width, lets say I want a column of width 77%. I would like to be able to do a class like this:

```
<div class="Col-50 Col-20 Col-5 Col-2">Content</div>
```

and in my CSS I would have these classes defined according to their respective percentages.

My problem is. The last class here, would be all that is applied. giving me a 2% column instead of the 77% column I intended.

Is there any magic CSS trick that will allow me to do some sort of additive % like what I am thinking or is this a JavaScript the only option.

I could do this in JavaScript but I want to avoid using JavaScript / jQuery or other code apart from HTML5/CSS3 at all costs because I want to remove external dependencies. While rare, it is still possible to disable JavaScript in browsers and I want my system to work without it if possible.

I also know I could us SCSS / LESS etc but ultimately the end result would be a very large CSS file filled with almost every % between 0 and 100. This is not my goal.

Comment: "According to CSS rules, the last class, that of Col-2, would be all that is applied." I don't believe that is correct at all. There order in which classes are applied has no relevance to the weight of a class. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade

Comment: What does your css look like?  Jason is right.

Comment: @Jason - Perhaps I misunderstand. Are you saying that if I have the classes specified, defined with nothing but the respective widths, that my end result for the specified code will not be a column of 2%.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers It might be 2%, however, it has nothing to do with the order of classes in the class attribute of the div. Rather, it would have to do with the order of the CSS classes defined in the stylesheet. There are a number of factors that determine the cascading nature of stylesheets. Specificity, how it is defined, order in which it is defined (not referenced from HTML), and important. The article provided above gives more clarity on the matter.

Comment: @Jason thanks for letting me know this. I will clarify the question with an edit.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers What you're trying to do is impossible with CSS and completely impractical. If I want an element of width 77% I'm going to give it `width:77%`, not 4 classes

Comment: @ZachSaucier - I guess its a matter of preference. Do you have a heavy css file with every possible percentage defined, or do you keep a light css file in which case it may mean getting a slightly heavier dom. My preference would be the dom side as chances are most of the percentages defined in the CSS will go unused. But this is just me. Im not saying its right.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers I use the widths I need, nothing more. On a regular website that usually maxes out around 10 per page which is hardly anything in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with CSS alone. CSS is a styling language, so (with the exception of calc() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) it doesn't have math calculations. It really isn't designed to compound values in that matter. Even a preprocessor like SASS/Less, I don't believe, would be able to accomplish that since the preprocessing is on the CSS side, not the HTML side. Perhaps an HTML preprocessor?

Either way, I'm not sure I follow the benefit of the class; adding 4 classes just to specify a width seems superfluous.

Maybe if they come out with "Compounding Style Sheets"? :)

Comment: The calc is interesting. Thanks for your answer. However I also think you are right and so in a short while, when I see what others post, I may accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

no it isn't possible, At some point you would have to have 100 classes for the width. If you are set on staying css only. I would write a CSS generator that basically loops through and creates the redundant code and saves it to a file for you. Then you could go in and add to the file as needed.